# Optimizing procedure with batch insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

So I have this procedure

```
do
$$
    declare
        article_id varchar(64);
        path       text[];
    begin
        for article_id, path in (
              with cte1 as (
                  select a.id, sg.value::jsonb as study_group, sg.ordinality - 1 as study_group_num
                    from t1 a
                    cross join lateral (
                            select *
                              from jsonb_array_elements_text(a.document -> 'studyGroups' -> 'studyGroups')
                                  with ordinality oclass_id(value)
                            ) as sg
              ),

                   cte2 as (
                       select osg.id,
                              osg.study_group_num,
                              pv.value::jsonb ->> 'parameterName'              as parameter_name,
                              (pv.value::jsonb ->> 'termNotFound')::text::bool as term_not_found,
                              pv.ordinality - 1                                as measured_parameter_num
                         from cte1 osg
                         cross join lateral (
                                 select *
                                   from jsonb_array_elements_text(osg.study_group -> 'measuredParameters' -> 'parameterValues')
                                       with ordinality oclass_id(value)
                                 ) as pv
                   )


            select mp.id,
                   '{studyGroups,studyGroups,' ||
                   mp.study_group_num ||
                   ',measuredParameters,parameterValues,' ||
                   mp.measured_parameter_num || ',termNotFound' || '}' as path
              from (
                  select m.id,
                         m.parameter_name,
                         m.term_not_found,
                         m.study_group_num,
                         m.measured_parameter_num
                    from cte2 m
              ) mp
              left join tab i on i.name = mp.parameter_name
             where (not mp.term_not_found
                 or mp.term_not_found is null)
               and i.id is null -- 108671
        )
            loop
                update t1 a
                   set document = jsonb_set(document, path, true::text::jsonb)
                 where a.id = article_id;
            end loop;
    end
$$;
```

it executes really slow like ~3 minutes, the problem is with loop update which executes around ~100k times.

I have tried changing it to batch update, but I fail to implement it. The problem is each id can have multiple paths and when I modify this to batch update each id only updates once, is there any way to make things better ?

Comment: Where is `article_id` coming from?

Comment: Instead of writing a loop in PL/pgSQL, writw a single `UPDATE ... FROM`.

Comment: my bad article_id is supposed to be id, the one in the for condition for article_id, path in ( ...

Comment: 1) Correct the code in your question. 2) As @LaurenzAlbe posted, while use a LOOP when you can just use  `UPDATE`?

Comment: don't use a loop, that's slow by design. Use a data set and proces this set just once

Comment: Im using loop because of logic, the main query returns around 100k rows with 2 columns id and path, and in the result id-s can repeat because each of them can have different path, when I perform simple update each id updates only once, the other cases are ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/bBDttdnc):

```sql
create table test (
  id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
  document jsonb);
insert into test (document) values 
  ('{"a":{"b":[{"c01":1,"c02":2},{"c11":3,"c12":4}]}}'),
  ('{"a":{"b":[{"c01":1,"c02":2},{"c11":3,"c12":4}]}}');
create table update_batch(id int,path text[],val int);
insert into update_batch values 
 (1,'{a,b,0,c01}'::text[],101),
 (1,'{a,b,1,c11}'::text[],111),
 (1,'{a,b,1,c12}'::text[],112),
 (2,'{a,b,0,c02}'::text[],202),
 (2,'{a,b,1,c11}'::text[],211);
update test set document=jsonb_set(document,
                                   path,
                                   to_jsonb(val) )
from update_batch as new where test.id=new.id
returning test.*;
```

| id | document |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a": {"b": [{"c01": 101, "c02": 2}, {"c11": 3, "c12": 4}]}} |
| 2 | {"a": {"b": [{"c01": 1, "c02": 202}, {"c11": 3, "c12": 4}]}} |

The `update_batch` requests 3 changes for the first id, 2 for the the next one. A plain `update...from update_batch` is going to apply only a single change requested for each `id` which is what [you observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77261255/optimizing-procedure-with-batch-insert#comment136212046_77261255):

> when I perform simple update each id updates only once, the other cases are ignored

There's a warning about that in [the notes under `UPDATE` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8):

> a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

Your solution is perfectly viable, although you overshot a bit: you're issuing one update per change, per row. As the doc suggests, you can merge/squash your changes so that `update` only sees the final state that you want. Once you merge the changes, you're applying them all with a single `update`.

```sql
with recursive update_rounds as (
  select row_number()over(partition by id), * from update_batch
),
update_per_round as (
  select 1 as round_n,
         t.id,
         jsonb_set(t.document,
                   u.path,
                   to_jsonb(u.val)) as new_document
  from update_rounds u join test t using(id)
  where u.row_number=1
  union all 
  select round_n+1,
         id,
         jsonb_set(t.new_document,
                   u.path,
                   to_jsonb(u.val))
  from update_rounds u join update_per_round t using(id)
  where u.row_number=round_n+1
),
squashed_updates as (
  select distinct on (id) id, new_document 
  from update_per_round order by id,round_n desc
)
update test 
set document=new_document
from squashed_updates s
where test.id=s.id
returning test.*;
```

| id | document |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a": {"b": [{"c01": 101, "c02": 2}, {"c11": 111, "c12": 112}]}} |
| 2 | {"a": {"b": [{"c01": 1, "c02": 202}, {"c11": 211, "c12": 4}]}} |

It adds order to the changes using [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), then applies them in that order, [in rounds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) (you can see them [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0urOQ4mK)). At the end, the final state of the `document` for each `id`, as of the last round it was processed in ([`distinct on...order by id,round_n desc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)), is returned and passed on to the outer `update`.

Comment: I remember you also added an example there, seems you have deleted it, was it a wrong example ? because I have the tab opened, and was gonna look at it now :)

Comment: @czauto That's right, after posting I thought of a case where that example would break so I retracted it. [Here's one that doesn't break that way.](https://dbfiddle.uk/7khWuUEj) The idea was to add something more resembling your structure, but since you haven't shown samples and cardinalities, it's only meant to illustrate the point.

Comment: Okay, thank you one more time for good explanation, and another thanks for the example.

Comment: idk why, but this works even slower :(

Comment: In my brief tests on a 6k sample in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JA-vGsZJ), it's significantly faster: `do` block takes 16s, this takes 3s. If you're facing problems implementing this, it might be worth opening a new question to show what you've created and how you're measuring it. A `create table` with mock/sample `insert` statements and `create`s for indexes and constraints would be very helpful. It's also helpful to have the output of `explain analyze verbose` for either the recursively squashed update you're measuring and the query you loop over in the `do` block.

Comment: @Zagarek the problem (in my understanding) is the depth of recursion as in my case there are ids with even 40 round_n

Comment: @czauto That would make sense - with recursive cte's you're quite often one typo away from unreasonable memory consumption. You can always try the middle ground: instead of squashing everything into a single update, you can loop over `update_rounds` and run one update per round. Updating all target rows simultaneously once per round is still less than running one update one per round, for each record individually. Still, without looking at the code and samples it's a blind guess on my part and this could just slow things down compared to (fixed/properly set up) recursion-based unary update.